# How to make a custom nav for the WP pluggin LayerSlider

Tags: wordpress

Has someone already built a custom nav for the WP pluggin LayerSlider ?
I've found this page related to a custom nav example but I can't make it work. http://pastebin.com/YHBFk1CR.
Does anyone have an online working example? Heres an example of what I'm try to do : http://www.brafton.com/
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WP LayerSlider has an integrated [Drag & Drop Builder](http://1.s3.envato.com/files/61535685/LayerSliderWP-styles-editor.jpg). Check out the screenshot, and notice the row "Layout & Positions". Use those input fields or manually move the selected the "layer" with your mouse / keyboard arrows.

Also, consider locally building your creation, visit [Insant WP](http://www.instantwp.com/) to start building more efficiently (zero lag).

--

```
WP Admin > Appearance > Menu > "create new menu" > Save Menu
```

If you **register second nav**, you'll take advantage of the powerful WP Menu function.

--

*Was this response not what your looking for?*

Plainly put, your using a tool that is not efficient at [creating the results you want](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/wordpress/). You may also just want to [download FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html) (being used on Brafton).

Send me an email if you require any files / help.

Comment: Above link resolves to: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/on-adding-second-menu-to-twenty-eleven